# Memory leak on simple HTTPRIO

Tags: delphi, memory, delphi-xe2, memory-leaks

I'm having a memory leak when I quit my application on the THTTPRIO object that I created.

I have my webservice defined as followed:

```
type
  TSimpleWebService = class
  protected
    FHTTPRIO : THTTPRIO;
  public
    constructor Create(URL : String);
    property HTTPRIO : THTTPRIO read FHTTPRIO;
  end;

implementation

constructor TSimpleWebService.Create(URL : String);
begin
  FHTTPRIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
  FHTTPRIO.URL := URL;
end;
```

I am testing/creating the webservice as followed (CustomerCare is my webservice interface):

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  webservice: customercare;
begin
  webservice := GetSimpleCustomerCareService;
  webservice := nil;
  frmMain.Close;
end;

function TfrmMain.getSimpleCustomerCareService: CustomerCare;
var
  webservice: TSimpleWebService;
begin
  webservice := TSimpleWebService.Create('http://this.is.a.test');
  Result := webservice.HTTPRIO as CustomerCare;
end;
```

When I click Button1, I'm not really doing anything but create the webservice, set it to nil again and quit the application. At that point (with ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutDown := True), I get an unexpected memory leak of 12 bytes on TSimpleWebService.

I have tried adding a destructor Destroy but it does not appear to be called.

What am I missing?

Thanks for your input,
Jan

oh yeah, I'm on XE2 Windows 2003. In addition to the memory leak on TSimpleWebservice, I also get a memory leak on a TDictionary object but I have no clue where that one is coming from. When I compile and run the same project on XE4/Windows 7, I only get the TSimpleWebservice memory leak.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your second question:

> oh yeah, I'm on XE2 Windows 2003. In addition to the memory leak on TSimpleWebservice, I also get a memory leak on a TDictionary object but I have no clue where that one is coming from. When I compile and run the same project on XE4/Windows 7, I only get the TSimpleWebservice memory leak.

There is a memoryleak in wsdllookup.pas, copy this file to your project and find this piece of code

```
destructor TWSDLLookup.Destroy;
begin
  ClearWSDLLookup;
  inherited;
end;
```

Change it to:

```
destructor TWSDLLookup.Destroy;
begin
  ClearWSDLLookup;
  Flookup.Free;   // this was missing!!!!
  inherited;
end;
```

As you found out, this error has been fixed in the more recent Delphi versions